# ASP.NET MVC Bootstrap dynamic modal content

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using MVC 5 and I have a `<button>` for each record in the `viewModel` as follows:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Questions.Single().QuestionType)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model =>model.Questions.Single().Scheme)
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Questions)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionType)
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >
                View
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

`Foreach (Var item in Model.Questions)`, there will be a `button` that opens up a `modal`. However, I want this `modal` to load different contents based on the `item.id` from `Model.Questions`. How can I do this?

Comment: jquery ajax would be the way

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use bootstrap modal dialog with ajax to load the details/view partial view result to the modal dialog.

First, add a new css class to the button, which we will use to wire up the click event later to fire up the modal dialog. Also we will generate the url to the details view using the `Url.Action` html helper method and keep that in html5 data attribute in the button(we will use this for our ajax call later)

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Questions)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm  modal-link"  
                 data-targeturl="@Url.Action("Details","Home",new { id = item.Id })">
            View
        </button>
     </td>
   </tr>
}
```

Now add the below code to your current view (or even the layout). This will act as the container for our modal dialog.

```
<!-- The below code is for the modal dialog -->
<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="modal-close-btn">X</a>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, let's wire up the `click` event on any element with "modal-link" css class. We added this classes to our buttons earlier.

```
$(function () {

    $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#modal-container").remove();

        $.get($(this).data("targeturl"), function (data) {

            $('<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade">'+
              '<div class="modal-content" id= "modalbody" >'+ 
                    data + '</div></div>').modal();

        });
    });
});
```

So when user clicks on the button, it reads the value of `targeturl` data attribute (*which is a URL with the item id value in the querystring*) and make an ajax call to that URL. In our case, It will make a call to the `Details` action method. So let's make sure that it returns the partial view result (out modal dialog content)

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    // Get the data using the Id and pass the needed data to view.

    var vm = new QuestionViewModel();

    var question = db.Questions.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.Id==id);
    // To do: Add null checks

    vm.Id = question.Id;
    vm.Title = question.Title;
    vm.Description = question.Description;

    return PartialView(vm);
}
```

And the partial view will have the needed html markup for the modal dialog.

```
@model YourNameSpace.QuestionViewModel
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <h4>@Model.Title</h4>
        <p>@Model.Description</p>
        <p>Some other content for the modal </p>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @shyju, thanks for the teaching and it works fine.. however the modal appear to be fullscreen width and it does not have a fade effect..is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I'm sure it's too late to help the OP, but for anyone else reading this, you can avoid the fullscreen width and create the fade effect by cutting the bottom code snippet (`<div class="modal-content">...</div>`) and pasting it inside an outer `<div class="modal-dialog">[paste here]</div>`

Comment: This works very nice.  By the way to avoid the fullscreen how Dave mentions, ponury-kostek (below's other answer in conjunction with this answer) does the trick!  Great job Shyju.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have dynamic modal, this code useful for you.(I hope so)

```
<table class="table table-hover "  >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sıra</th>
                    <th>PC Adı</th>
                    <th>Kullanıcı</th>
                    <th>Marka/Model</th>
                    <th>Departman</th>
                    <th>İşletim Sistemi</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @{int i1 = 1;
                    foreach (var item in Model.devices)
                    {
                        <tr style="font-size:13px" >
                            <td>@i1</td>
                            <td>@item.DeviceName</td>
                            <td>@item.DeviceOwner</td>
                            <td>@item.DeviceBrand</td>
                            <td>@item.DeviceDepartment</td>
                            <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@i1"> @Model.softwares[i1 - 1].OSName</td>
                            <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@i1">@Model.softwares[i1 - 1].OfficeName</td>
                        </tr>

                        <div id="@i1" class="modal fade"  role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">İşletim Sistemi ve Office Detayları</h4>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p>OS Adı:@Model.softwares[i1 - 1].OSName</p>
                                            <p>OS Lisans:@Model.softwares[i1 - 1].OSLicenceCode</p>
                                            <p>OS Fatura:@Model.softwares[i1 - 1].OSBillCode</p>
                                            <p>Office Adı:@Model.softwares[i1 - 1].OfficeName</p>
                                            <p>Office Lisans:@Model.softwares[i1 - 1].OfficeLicenceCode</p>
                                            <p>Office Fatura:@Model.softwares[i1 - 1].OfficeBillCode</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        i1++;
                    }
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Shjiu.Code is working fine.To change the model fullscreen,add this code.
' .

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#modal-container").remove();
        $.get($(this).data("targeturl"), function (data) {
            $('<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade">  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="width:500px;>' +
                '<div class="modal-content" id= "modalbody" >' + 
                data + 
                '</div></div></div>').modal();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This modification along with Shyju's original code above works very nice!  The popup is now centered.