# How can I use a Bootstrap Alert popup insde an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

In my `MVC` project I'm using following AJAX call to a controller where an action method is deleting a record. If record is deleted successfully I use a normal `Alert(...)` popup to inform the user that the record was deleted successfully. **Question**: Is there a way I can instead use a Bootstrap dialog in the following AJAX call - if so, how?

I'm using ASP.NET Core in VS2015 that has default built-in functionality. No AngularJS.

```
$('#DeleteBtnID').click(function (e) {

    var PK_id = $(this).val();    
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("TestAction", "TestContr")',
        data: { id: PK_id },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Record Deleted Successfully');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert(jqXHR.statusCode);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to keep the markup needed for the modal dialog in your current page (or the layout file)

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="modalMsg"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>                  
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Next, In your ajax success call (Assuming your server code returns a 200 response when it successfully deletes stuff), you simply need to update the content of the modalMsg element.

```
var pkId = 33;
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Home")',
    data: { id: pkId },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#modalMsg").text('deleted successfully');
        $('#myModal').modal();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        // to do : handle error
    }
});
```

Here, you are only updating the p tag content of the modal body. You can change this code to update the modal dialog title, hide/show some button etc.

You can improve this to simply have even minimal markup in your page have your action method returns the modal content markup as explained in this post

[ASP.NET MVC Bootstrap dynamic modal content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984105/asp-net-mvc-bootstrap-dynamic-modal-content/42984614#42984614)

There is a nice js library called [bootbox js](http://bootboxjs.com/) which makes your life a little easier. Basically bootbox takes care of building the markup for the modal dialog in your page. With this all you have to do is call their method.

Include the bootbox library to your page.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```

Call the method as needed.

```
var pkId = 33;
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Home")',
    data: { id: pkId },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        bootbox.alert("This is the default alert!");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        // to do : handle error
    }
});
```

Comment: In your first suggestion (w/o bootbox) I'm getting the following error in my Chrome Dev tool's `Sources` tab: `TypeError: $(...).modal() is not a function`. I also noticed that in VS2015 editor's `Intellisense` had not recognized `modal()` in `$('#myModal').modal();` so I had hard-coded `.modal()` part.

Comment: Did you include bootstrap library js files in the page ? check the view source and make sure that the library is included/loaded properly before calling any methods from that.

Comment: Bootstrap was included by default when I created the ASP.NET Core 1.1 project using VS2015's default project template called `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)`. On the same page I'm using another delete confirm modal/dialog that is working fine. But when I click on the Delete button of this dialog, the AJAX call successfully deletes the record and the error occurs when `success: function (data) {...}` part of the AJAX call uses your `$('#myModal').modal();` function.