# MVC modal showing in full screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Today I came across with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984105/asp-net-mvc-bootstrap-dynamic-modal-content), I tried doing what was in the project and came across with the OP's problem about the full screen modal. I saw a solution below about about cutting the div and pasting it in an outer div.

I did what was in the solution but what happens is that the full modal div is retained and the normal popup shows.

[image]

If I add it to the script, no popup shows but backdrop changes.

[image]

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

**PARENT VIEW BUTTON**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm  modal-link" data-targeturl="@Url.Action("_Popup","Application",new { MotorId = item.motor_id, Serialno = item.serialno, AppNo = item.application_no, Remarks = item.remarks })"> View
</button>
```

**PARENT MODAL**

```
<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="modal-close-btn">X</a>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function () {

   $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

       $("#modal-container").remove();

       $.get($(this).data("targeturl"), function (data) {

       $('<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade">' + '<div class="modal-content" id="modalbody" >' + data + '</div></div>').modal();

         });
     });
});
```

**PARTIAL VIEW**

```
@model iVehicle.ViewModel.FranchiseViewModel

<div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <p>Some content here</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @John Clarence Castro, add what you tried from code side in your question. So, that we can help you.

Comment: @yash I have added my code above Sir. Thanks